# Mongoose: How do I run a collection.find() for multiple TYPES of queries, one of which includes keyword searching?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, find

I am taking my first JavaScript class, and I am trying to create a web app where I can search for specific information (database in mongoDB) through a web browser's form.

Here is what my data schema looks like (simplified and showing only relevant fields):

```
const Posts = new mongoose.Schema({
  postType: {type: String, required: true}, // "Mentee" or "Mentor"
  area: {type: String, required: true}, // "Academics" or "Career"
  postName: {type: String, required: true}, // "Should I .... ?"
});
```

Currently my form allows the user to search for maximum three criteria (as shown above), which are `postType`, `area`, `postName`. The user can search for only 1 property up to 3 properties! If the user searches for nothing, the web should return ALL results!

Here is my code for `.find()`.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const queryObj = {};
  if (req.query.postNameQ) {
    queryObj.postName = req.query.postNameQ;
  }
  if (req.query.postTypeQ) {
    queryObj.postType = req.query.postTypeQ;
  }
  if (req.query.areaQ) {
    queryObj.area = req.query.areaQ;
  }
  Posts.find(queryObj, (err, found) => {
    if (err) {
      // error handling
    }
    console.log('queryObj: ', queryObj);
    res.render('home', {found: found,
      timesAccessed: req.session.timesAccessed});
  });
});
```

I have reached a point where I can search for the results that "exactly" match what I typed in my form. For example, if I search for `postType=Mentee`, I can get the results whose `postType` is `Mentee`, but if I search for `postType=Men`, I will not get any result.

However, I want to be able to get the results whose (given) property includes whatever is inserted into the form without "exactly" matching the results.  For example, I to be able to search for the posts whose `postName` contain "Should I", because now nothing will show up if I type in "should I", since all the posts' `postName` do not exactly match "Should I'.

I have read SO articles whose solution is to use something like `db.collection.find( {propertyName: { $regex: "Programming"} } );` which I can do if I am only search for one property of a schema. BUT, since I want to search for one or multiple properties, I can't.

Please assist, and thank you very much for your help!

Comment: have you tried AND operator ?

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I have not. Could you please show me an example of how I might use the AND operator? Also, since the user can search for none or one or two or three properties, I am not sure if AND would be appropriate just by reading your comment.

Comment: There is OR operator, seems like this what you want

Comment: I am assuming you are referring to `$or`, something like: `db.inventory.find( { $or: [ { postType: "Mentee" }, { area: "Career" } ] } )`. However, since the user can choose to not enter any query for, for example, `postType`, I can have an empty field for `postType` in this case, and I am struggling with how I would syntactically implement it in my code. Could you please give a code example for using `$or` for my situation?

Comment: Thank you for the help but I don't think you understood my question at all. Length should not matter here because I am trying to search for posts that INCLUDE my query. My example and the explanation for why I cannot use regular regex should have given you a clear idea of what I wanted to achieve. If I type for "Men" for `postType`, it should get me all posts with their `postType` property that includes "Men" which would apply to both "Mentee" and "Mentor", and the same applies for `postName` and `area`.